# Multiple WHERE clauses with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked at a bunch of similar stackoverflow questions but I haven't been able to figure this out.

```
                    WHERE `Table1`.`Column1` = 'criteria1'
                    AND `Table1`.`Column2` = 'criteria2'
                    AND `Table1`.`Column3` LIKE 'criteria3'
                    AND IF(EXISTS IN `Table2`, (`Table2`.`Delete` <> 2, `Table2`.`SectionId` IS NOT NULL), '')
```

I'm trying to execute a query with five `WHERE` clauses, where the last two are based on the condition that the row exists in the joined Table2. If the condition is false, throw in an empty string ''.

I've tried variations of the above code but it's incorrect syntax. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Can I use an IF inside a `WHERE` clause like that?

EDIT (here's the full query...):

```
        $sql_query = "SELECT
                    `Courses`.`Id` AS CourseId,
                    IFNULL(`Courses`.`CourseName`, '') AS CourseName,
                    IF(`Courses`.`CourseNumber` > '', `Courses`.`CourseNumber`, -1) AS CourseNumber,
                    IFNULL(`Courses`.`CourseDepartment`, '') AS CourseDepartment,
                    IFNULL(`Courses`.`Notes`, '') AS CourseNotes,
                    IFNULL(`Courses`.`Year`, '') AS CourseYear,
                    IFNULL(`Courses`.`CourseType`, '') AS CourseType,
                    `Sections`.`Id` AS SectionId,
                    IFNULL(`Sections`.`SectionNumber`, '') AS SectionNumber,
                    IFNULL(`Sections`.`SectionName`, '') AS SectionName,

                    `StudentsCourses`.`CustomerId` AS CustomerId,

                    CONCAT(`Courses`.`Id`, '-', `Sections`.`Id`, '-', `StudentsCourses`.`FirstName`, `StudentsCourses`.`LastName`, '_', `StudentsCourses`.`TeacherEmail`) AS TempCustomerId,
                    IFNULL(`StudentsCourses`.`FirstName`, '') AS StudentFirstName,
                    IFNULL(`StudentsCourses`.`LastName`, '') AS StudentLastName,
                    IFNULL(`Customers`.`Email`, IFNULL(`StudentsCourses`.`StudentEmail`, '')) AS StudentEmail,
                    IFNULL(`StudentsCourses`.`TeacherFirstName`, '') AS TeacherFirstName,
                    IFNULL(`StudentsCourses`.`TeacherLastName`, '') AS TeacherLastName,
                    IF(`StudentsCourses`.`CustomerId` IS NOT NULL, `Customers`.`CustomerName`, CONCAT(`StudentsCourses`.`FirstName`, ' ', `StudentsCourses`.`LastName`)) AS FullName,
                    IF(`StudentsCourses`.`CustomerId` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(REPLACE(`Customers`.`CustomerName`, ' ', ''), '_', `Customers`.`Email`), CONCAT(`StudentsCourses`.`FirstName`, `StudentsCourses`.`LastName`, '_', `StudentsCourses`.`TeacherEmail`)) AS NameKey,
                    `Customers`.`UserRoleId` AS UserRoleId,
                    `Customers`.`MagentoId` AS MagentoId,
                    `StudentsCourses`.`StudentId` AS StudentId,
                    `SiteProfile`.`StudentIdField` AS StudentIdField,
                    `SiteProfile`.`SchoolEmailDomain` AS SchoolEmailDomain,
                    `StudentsCourses`.`Id` AS StudentsCoursesId,
                    IFNULL(`Orders`.`Id`, '') AS OrderId
                FROM `Courses`
                    LEFT JOIN `StudentsCourses` ON `Courses`.`Id` = `StudentsCourses`.`CourseId`
                    LEFT JOIN `BooksCourses` ON `Courses`.`Id` = `BooksCourses`.`CourseId`
                    LEFT JOIN `Products` ON `BooksCourses`.`ISBN` = `Products`.`ISBN`
                    LEFT JOIN `EbookVendors` ON `Products`.`EbookVendorId` = `EbookVendors`.`Id`
                    LEFT JOIN `Sections` ON `Sections`.`Id` = `StudentsCourses`.`SectionId`
                    LEFT JOIN `Customers` ON `StudentsCourses`.`CustomerId` = `Customers`.`Id`
                    LEFT JOIN `SiteProfile` ON `Courses`.`SchoolCode` = `SiteProfile`.`SchoolCode`
                    LEFT JOIN `Orders` ON `Customers`.`Id` = `Orders`.`CustomerId`

                    WHERE `Courses`.`SchoolCode` = '{$criteria["school_code"]}'
                    AND `Courses`.`Year` = {$criteria["year"]}
                    AND `Courses`.`CourseType` LIKE '{$criteria["term"]}'
                    AND `StudentsCourses`.`Delete` <> 2
                    AND `StudentsCourses`.`SectionId` IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: That exist is incoherent, did you find that syntax used somewhere or were you just guessing? [MySQL Documentation for EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: Which field should exist in Table2? Can you post the full query?

Comment: ..and "throw in an empty string" for what? These are boolean conditions, not field selections.

Comment: I didn't find this syntax anywhere. I'm just guessing since I haven't found anything close to what I'm trying to doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear exactly what you are asking, but I am guessing something *like* this condition *might* be what you are looking for:

```
AND (StudentCourses.CourseId IS NULL 
     OR (`StudentsCourses`.`Delete` <> 2
         AND `StudentsCourses`.`SectionId` IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
```

Edit: It would best if you edited your question to explain in plain language what you want the condition to do, as it is not apparent at all what the intent was from the syntax you originally presented.

Comment: This is probably right, but it didn't work for me. I think my whole query needs to be redone.